# Можно ли запомнить как-то данные из запроса, чтобы не делать лишних обращений в базу данных django?

Tags: python, sql, django

```
latest_artiсles_list = Article.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date').values('article_text', 'article_title', 'slug')
popular = latest_artiсles_list.order_by('views')[:4]
```

В данном коде выполняется два запроса из-за особенностей джанго orm, можно ли как-то запомнить первый запрос, чтобы укоротить число обращений в бд?

Comment: Вы меняете порядок сортировки и из базы могут вернуться другие объекты, поэтому избавиться от второго запроса невозможно. И orm тут вообще ни при чём, это банальная логика

Comment: Ну и да, запрос выполняется только при попытке обратиться к объектам внутри queryset. Так как в показанном коде таких обращений нет, то выполнится ноль запросов

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно. Вы можете сохранить результат первого запроса в переменную, чтобы использовать ее для выполнения второго запроса, вместо того, чтобы выполнять его повторно. Пример:

```
latest_articles_list = Article.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date').values('article_text', 'article_title', 'slug')

# Сохраняем результаты первого запроса в переменную
results = latest_articles_list

# Используем результаты первого запроса для выполнения второго запроса
popular = results.order_by('views')[:4]
```

Иначе, скорее всего, не получится